# create aws subnet tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I am trying to create a subnet name tag but I'm getting the error. I have no idea what is causing the error. The subnet was successfully created, however, there is an error creating the tag name.

```html
pub_subnetid = pub_subnet['Subnet']['SubnetId']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```html
def addvpcnametag(self, tagid, resourcename):
        print("creating tag name")
        return self.client.create_tags(
            Resources=[tagid],
            Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': resourcename}])
```

In the main i have:

```html
 pub_subnet = vpc.addnew_subnet(tag_id, '10.0.2.0/24')
    pub_subnetid = pub_subnet['Subnet']['SubnetId']
    print("Adding public subnet name tag")

    publicsubnetname_tag = 'Public-subnet'
    vpc.addvpcnametag(pub_subnetid, publicsubnetname_tag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that sets the `Name` tag on a given subnet:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

subnet_id = 'subnet-abcd1234'

subnet = ec2_resource.Subnet(subnet_id)
subnet.create_tags(
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'Foo'
        },
    ]
)
```